# finding out memory allocation hotspots in java

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

Our GC is working hard and we have some pauses that we want to decrease.
We have some memory allocation issues that we want to solve before or while we are tweaking with the actual JVM GC args.

I would like to know which objects are making the GC sweat:

1. is there a way to know which objects are evacuated every time the GC
   is working?
2. is there a way to know which objects are moved between
   areas every time the GC is working?
3. Is there a way to know which objects are in Eden area?

I am working extensively with Jprofiler and Memory Analyzer. 
I would like to get this information on a running application in my staging environment.

Comment: The best option available is to minimise the objects created by looking for allocation hotspots. You can also look at retained size and number by class to determine which classes to concentrate on.

Comment: Isn't it a better idea to track allocations?

Comment: What we are trying to find out is what objects survive the young generation and get to Eden or Old, although they are temporary.

Answer (score 4):

For 2 and 3, you can use the `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` and `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` flags with either Oracle or OpenJDK `java` executable during a run session of your application

Comment: How Can I see specific Object information in it? which classes are being cleared? how much  time they reside in the heap?

Comment: Not specific objects, but overall object behavior, check [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ibmtools2/index.html) for a visual tool recommendation and for an example use case

Comment: ok, that is not the question, I am aware of PrintGCDetails and pringGCTimeStamps and they are not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For question 1,  [Phantom References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) can be used. This will allow you to be notified when an object is GC'ed (or GC-able).

As to the other two, I don't quite know.

Answer (score 2):

Finding out memory allocation in a running JVM maybe take great efforts.

Instead, you can checkout hotspot [source code](http://openjdk.java.net/) and add you own logs when GC or allocation. Compile you own hotspot and trace the logs.

---

Using the `-XX:+PrintCompilation` can help you.

The `-XX:+PrintCompilation` flag output looks something like this:

```
1  sb   java.lang.ClassLoader::loadClassInternal  (6 bytes)     
2  b    java.lang.String::lastIndexOf  (12 bytes)
3  s!b  java.lang.ClassLoader::loadClass  (58 bytes)
```

Flags correspond to:

```
b    Blocking compiler (always set for client)  
*    Generating a native wrapper    
%    On stack replacement   
!    Method has exception handlers  
s    Synchronized method
```

[More details](http://blog.joda.org/2011/08/printcompilation-jvm-flag.html).

Comment: sounds interesting, will try to dig around it, might be really hard tough.

Answer (score 2):

We will probably try to use some byte code instrumentation for adding finalize (maybe to Object) that will give us this information in the log.

Comment: not sure if the finalize will help here, since instances with a finalize method may or may not be collected during a GC. This can skew allocation/deallocation behavior pretty badly.

Answer (score 1):

**Content of the OldGen space:** You can find out which objects reside in the OldGen.  You need to print histograms before and after Full GC: `-XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC -XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC`. And since a YoungGen collection is executed before the Full GC, these **Histograms will show you the content of the Old generation**.

**Detecting prematurely promoted objects:** To determine if any instances are promoted early, you need to study the Histograms to see which classes are expected to reside in the `OldGen` and which classes should be seen only in the `YoungGen`. This cannot be done automatically, you need to reason about the purpose of each class and its instance to determine if the object is temporary or not.

**Content of the YoungGen/Eden space:** I have not found a way howto distinguish which objects reside e.g. in Eden. As you probably know, *jProfiler* and *MemoryAnalyzer* can dump the heap but that will not tell you in which area the objects reside. But, You can also take histogram snapshots in regular intervals and then write a simple script that will parse the output and tell you which instances grow fastest, use : `jmap -histo $pid`.